# Unable to install lws package(No such file or directory: '_version.py')

Tags: package-management, software-installation, python

```
(my_env35) ubuntu@<some_ip>:~/voice_cloning/deepvoice3_pytorch$ pip install lws
Collecting lws

enter code hereUsing cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ee/14/b1d07a911f7e50f5c2d8ab1b65021a79232eb6267cba203afe20e50b3caa/lws-1.2.1.tar.gz
    ERROR: Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    ERROR: Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-pn5vxqb4/lws/setup.py", line 27, in <module>
        verstrline = open(VERSIONFILE, "rt").read()
      File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/my_env35/lib/python3.5/codecs.py", line 895, in open
        file = builtins.open(filename, mode, buffering)
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '_version.py'
    ----------------------------------------

ERROR: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-pn5vxqb4/lws/
```

I also tried downloading the source package from GitHub(https://github.com/Jonathan-LeRoux/lws/tree/master/python) and then installing it from setup.py but the same error occurs

I am on Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS

Tried installing on python version 3.5 and 3.7

Comment: It looks like you are using anaconda python - you may find this helpful: [Using Pip to install packages to Anaconda Environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41060382/using-pip-to-install-packages-to-anaconda-environment)

Comment: same error occurs even I don't use anaconda environment